# Regex to select quote parameters

Tags: regex, expressionengine, textmatebundles

I am putting together a syntax highlighter for the Expression Engine templating language. I am trying to grab double quotes and their value only inside of an `{if}` tag.

**Example**

```
{if layout:test == "test" || another == "value"}
 {if:elseif param == "value"}
 {if:else}
{/if}
```

**Regular Expression**

```
{if.+?(?=")(")([^"]*)(")
```

The problem is that it only ever captures the first one and not the next one. How can I make it select all of them within a conditional block only?

**Desired Matches**

```
"test", "value"
```

Comment: Your regex has a syntax error. Please correct it.

Answer (score 2):

### Brief

I would suggest breaking your logic into two parts (2 separate regular expressions). The first regex should match the if block and the second should match the variables within it. The reason you are unable to grab the second variable in the first `{if}` block is due to the way regular expressions work. They will only capture 1 group if you're matching a string (unless you explicitly tell it to potentially match 2 groups, in which case you won't capture the third group unless you do the same, etc.).

---

### Code

#### Capture blocks

[See this code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/XW2M4k/3)

```
{(?:(?<if>if(?=\s+))|(?<elseif>if:elseif(?=\s+)))\s*((?:[^"]*?|"[^"]*")*)\s*}
```

#### Gather variable values

[See this code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/ra4BHU/1)

```
[\w:]+\s*==\s*"([^"]*)"
```

---

### Results

#### Input - Capture blocks

```
{if layout:test == "test" || another == "}"}
 {if:elseif param == "value"}
 {if:else}
{/if}
```

#### Output - Capture blocks

- Group `if`

  - Group 3: `layout:test == "test" || another == "}"`
- Group `elseif`

  - Group 3: `param == "value"`

#### Input - Gather variable values

```
layout:test == "test" || another == "}"
param == "value"
```

#### Output - Gather variable values

```
test
}
value
```

---

### Explanation

#### Capture blocks

- `{` Match this character literally
- `(?:(?<if>if(?=\s+))|(?<elseif>if:elseif(?=\s+)))` Capture either `if` into group named **if**, which is followed by at least one whitespace character, or capture `if:elseif` into group named **elseif**, which is followed by at least one whitepsace character
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
- `((?:[^"]*?|"[^"]*")*)` Capture any number of either of the following

  - `[^"]*?` Match any character except `"` any number of times, but as few as possible
  - `"[^"]*"` Match a `"`, followed by any character except `"` any number of times, followed by `"`
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters

#### Gather varaible values

- `[\w:]+` Match any word character `\w` or colon `:` between one and unlimited times
- `\s*` Match any whitespace character any number of times
- `==` Match `==` literally
- `\s*` Match any whitespace character any number of times
- `"` Match `"` literally
- `([^"]*)` Capture any character except `"` any number of times
- `"` Match `"` literally